# Print each emit in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, socket.io

I'm trying to print my Messages in a Node.JS/Socket.JS Web-App.
In Firefox I've made the option, that he doesn't popup the normally Print-Dialog.

Now my Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // WebSocket
    var socket = io.connect();

    //register Printer
    socket.emit('join', {name:"print-direct"});
    // neue Nachricht
    var a = 0;
    socket.on('msg', function (data) {
        var zeit = new Date(data.zeit);
        var innerHTML = $('#content_text').html();

        $('#content_text').html(innerHTML+'<div class="msg" id="'+a+'">Name "+data.name+'</font><br><font size="+2">'+data.msg+'</font></div>');
        $('#'+a).printElement();
        $("#"+a).remove();
        a++;
    });
});
```

Do you Have an idea how i can fix this?

Thanks!

PS: This is the Print-Plugin I've used http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my rep is too low to comment, but is this code in your front-end? If so, you can simply use console.log in your javascript and it will show up in your developer console in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah this is the client code... but what can I do with a log in the console? I want to print it, yet :)

Comment: Oh I am sorry I misunderstood the question. I am not too familiar with this, but one thing I am wondering is if the `$("#"+a).remove();` line right after the print would make it not appear possibly?

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work.... so in the Console (Chrome) is a error in the jquery.printElement.js... something like "Opera is not defined"...